# How to combine the groupby(s) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes and I'd like to concatenate the groupby results using Python...How can I do that?

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Country':["US","CN","GB","US","DE","AU","CM","CU","CM"],'July Volume': [2541,3766,3071,1881,4653,1890,3203,1820,1411],
              'July Sales':[40264,40400,16135,41301,13757,45066,53709,42798,16184]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Country':["BA","CN","BE","US","AR","US","CM","CU","GB"],'Aug Volume':[4928,1665,4438,3241,4700,2304,2138,2692,4054],
              'Aug Sales':[18291,39776,41642,28364,21437,42000,56684,45179,23534]})
```

Groupby df1

```
df1.groupby('Country').agg({'July Sales':['count','sum']})
```

Groupby df2

```
df2.groupby('Country').agg({'Aug Sales':['count','sum']})
```

My expected results would be:
[image]

Because the actual data are really large with hundred of columns, I don't want to join them first...

Any thought and ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.concat()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) like this:

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Country').agg({'July Sales':['count','sum']})
df2 = df2.groupby('Country').agg({'Aug Sales':['count','sum']})

df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

df will look like:

```
    July Sales         Aug Sales
         count    sum      count    sum
AR         NaN    NaN          1  21437
AU           1  45066        NaN    NaN
BA         NaN    NaN          1  18291
BE         NaN    NaN          1  41642
CM           2  69893          1  56684
CN           1  40400          1  39776
CU           1  42798          1  45179
DE           1  13757        NaN    NaN
GB           1  16135          1  23534
US           2  81565          2  70364
```

Comment: Thank you. The answer helps me.